How can I run NVIDIA GPU code from containerd ctr?
I installed containerd using getting started guide from https://github.com/containerd/containerd/blob/main/docs/getting-started.md. Using ctr tool, I am able to run container like
sudo ctr run --runtime io.containerd.runc.v2 docker.io/library/nginx:latest nginx-runc ls

After this I installed NVIDIA driver and CUDA toolkit. It is working fine.

Followed nvidia-container-toolkit doc to install it.
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/libnvidia-container/stable/rpm/nvidia-container-toolkit.repo | \
  sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/nvidia-container-toolkit.repo
sudo yum install -y nvidia-container-toolkit

After this configured containerd using below command
sudo nvidia-ctk runtime configure --runtime=containerd
sudo systemctl restart containerd

It added below configuration in /etc/containerd/config.toml
     [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes]

        [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.nvidia]
          base_runtime_spec = ""
          cni_conf_dir = ""
          cni_max_conf_num = 0
          container_annotations = []
          pod_annotations = []
          privileged_without_host_devices = false
          privileged_without_host_devices_all_devices_allowed = false
          runtime_engine = ""
          runtime_path = ""
          runtime_root = ""
          runtime_type = "io.containerd.runc.v2"
          sandbox_mode = "podsandbox"
          snapshotter = ""

          [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".containerd.runtimes.nvidia.options]
            BinaryName = "/usr/bin/nvidia-container-runtime"
            CriuImagePath = ""
            CriuPath = ""
            CriuWorkPath = ""
            IoGid = 0
            IoUid = 0
            NoNewKeyring = false
            NoPivotRoot = false
            Root = ""
            ShimCgroup = ""
            SystemdCgroup = false

Now my question is how can I use this Nvidia runtime in the ctr tool?
